# Why does Sentinel 3 provide the georefences separately?

Tags: sentinel-3

I also posted this question on https://forum.step.esa.int/t/why-does-sentinel-3-store-the-geometry-separately/41287/1.

I am curious why it is necessary to store the georeferences separately in the geodetic_in.nc file.

I found in https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/4598082/Sentinel-3-SLSTR-Land-Handbook.pdf/ on page 19 that the reason for that is the conical scanner on the satellite.

However, I do not get it completely. I see that the recording is performed on a curve through the images (the ones provided at the end). But if I understand it correctly, the final georeferences in the geodetic_in.nc file are a choice and the the actual data is reprojected to these georefernces via nearest neighbor. Why do these georefences need to be irregular?